# Model has_many PaperclipModel. I have error "undefined method `img'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, has-many

I installed gem Paperclip, created two models

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizzerium
  attr_accessible :img, :pizzerium_id, :alt
    has_attached_file :img, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x70>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  self.per_page = 6
end
```

And Pizzerium

```
class Pizzerium < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :url, :city, :meta_tag, :text_shedule, :time_begin, :time_end, :week_begin, :week_end
end
```

If i write in controller this code:

```
@pizzerium = Pizzerium.where("city = ? AND url = ?", params[:city], params[:pizza]).first
@images = @pizzerium.images.all
```

and this code in view:

```
<%= image_tag @images.first.img.url(:medium) %>
```

it's works, but if i trying

```
@pizzs = Pizzerium.where("city = ?", params[:city]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

or

```
@pizzs = Pizzerium.includes(:images).where("city = ?", params[:city]).paginate(:page => params[:page])


<% @pizzs.each do |pizzerium| %>
<%= image_tag pizzerium.images.first.img.url %>
<% end %>
```

I see error:

> **NoMethodError in General#index**
>
> Showing /home/wwju/rails/pizza/app/views/general/index.html.erb where
>   line #14 raised:
>
> undefined method `img' for nil:NilClass

in rails console:

```
pizzs = Pizzerium.includes(:images).all
  Pizzerium Load (31.6ms)  SELECT "pizzeria".* FROM "pizzeria" 
  Image Load (10.3ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."pizzerium_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 32)
 => [#<Pizzerium id: 1, name: "Пицца-шляпа...
...

pizzs.first.images.first.img
 => /system/images/imgs/000/000/017/original/02.jpg?1369309592 

1.9.3p429 :027 > pizzs.each do |p|
1.9.3p429 :028 >     p.images.first.img
1.9.3p429 :029?>   end
NoMethodError: undefined method `img' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):28:in `block in irb_binding'
```

(If you find any mistakes, please, let me know, I'm working to improve my English.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pizzerium.images is nil. No image associated with pizzerium object.

```
add check pizzerium.images? 
<%= image_tag pizzerium.images.first.img.url if pizzerium.images? %>
```

Comment: undefined method `images?' for #<Pizzerium:0xaeb05dc>

Comment: if i write 

if pizzerium.images?

then i don't see errors, but don't see images

Comment: because there is no .images for that pizzerium object.

Comment: In pizzs object array. One of the 'p' image is not there means p.images is null.

Comment: puts "#{p.id}" inside each loop to find which 'p' id has no image assoicated. Got it?

Comment: <%= image_tag pizzerium.images.first.img.url if pizzerium.images.first? %> - it works